# Difference between account, wallet and deployed addresses: Remix IDE & Code

Tags: remix, addresses

When I am executing the program on the remix IDE (got from internet), it asks me the address, _wallet, which I am passing in the constructor. Remix IDE shows me 3 addresses: Account, Deploy _wallet and Deployed Contracts. In the code, I am using the only the wallet address retrieved from *wallet. What the statement*

```
wallet.transfer(msg.value)
```

would do? Will it transfer Ether to the Account address. What is the difference between the 3 address and their usage.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.4;
  contract MyContractEtherEvents {
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
    address payable wallet;
    event Purchase(
        address indexed _buyer,
        uint256 _amount
    );

    constructor(address payable _wallet) public {
        wallet = _wallet;
    }

    function() external payable {
        buyToken();
    }

    function buyToken() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += 1;
        wallet.transfer(msg.value);
        emit Purchase(msg.sender, 1);
    }
}
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between the 3 addresses?

- `Account`: the account that you are currently using in order to execute transactions (i.e., deploy contracts and/or call contract functions); It has to be unlocked on your environment
- `Deploy _wallet`: the input argument that you need to pass to the constructor of contract `MyContractEtherEvents` in order to deploy it
- `Deployed Contracts`: a list of addresses of contracts that you have already deployed

---

> What will the statement `wallet.transfer(msg.value)` do?

It will transfer the amount of ether that the user has just passed to your contract when he or she called the function; it will transfer that amount of ether from your contract to the address `wallet` (which you had passed as an input argument to the constructor of the contract when you deployed it); assuming that you have the private key of this address, you will be able to withdraw that amount, i.e., transfer it to anywhere you want.

Comment: In this program, user can only pass Ether to the wallet address. Can a user pass Ether to the Account address or to the Deployed contract address?

Comment: If I am assigning 2 to the value field and changing the wei to Ether, then 2 Ethers are deducted from account address and 2 Ether are added to the wallet address.